# How to get proxy addresses using https://microsoft.graph.com and GraphServiceClient

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to obtain proxy addresses, but the proxy addresses property returns null even though proxy addresses exist.

```
    GraphClientHelper graphClientHelper = new GraphClientHelper(tenantId);
        GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient = graphClientHelper.GetGraphServiceClient();
        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage user = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().GetAsync();
```

I get proxy addresses using https://windows.net and ActiveDirectoryCLient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to request `proxyAddresses` specifically.

For example:

```cs
var users = await graphClient.Users.Request().Select("id, mail, proxyAddresses").GetAsync();
```

Comment: It takes in UPN as proxy address which is not the right proxy address.

Comment: You mentioned that the proxy addresses exist. Do they exist in Azure AD also? In which field? You can take a look at your tenant's details through the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) or the [Azure Graph API Explorer](https://graphexplorer.azurewebsites.net/).

Comment: The UPN is also a proxyAddress.  I don't know if you can remove it from the list. On one tenant I have access to, the proxyAddresses for users that have been sync'ed with Azure AD Connect, contains all proxyAddreses (including X500 addresses) and also the Azure AD UPN (@tenant.onmicrosoft.com).

Comment: yes, it takes in UPN as proxy, I did a string comparison in if, to remove that, not sure if there is any other way.